# Is it possible to animate the BringIntoView method in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, scrollview

Is it possible to animate the BringIntoView method in WPF?  We want a nice animated transition of our `ScrollView` rather than having it just jump to the contained control.  How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **BringIntoView** raises the **RequestBringIntoView** event that bubbles up from that element. Typically that is handled by a **ScrollViewer** which queues the request and then ultimately calls the [MakeVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.makevisible.aspx) of the Panel in the **ItemsPresenter** (if it implements IScrollInfo and the CanContentScroll is true) or that of the **ScrollContentPresenter**. So either you would need to intercept the BringIntoView before the ScrollViewer catches it or you would need a custom Panel that implements IScrollInfo (i.e. it handles its own scrolling) and then you can determine how to make the container visible.